# How to find a US zip code in a string using regular expression?

Tags: python, regex

Fill in the code to check if the text passed includes a possible U.S. zip code, formatted as follows: exactly 5 digits, and sometimes, but not always, followed by a dash with 4 more digits. The zip code needs to be preceded by at least one space, and cannot be at the start of the text.

Couldn't produce the required output.

```
import re
def check_zip_code (text):
  result = re.search(r"\w+\d{5}-?(\d{4})?", text)
  return result != None

print(check_zip_code("The zip codes for New York are 10001 thru 11104.")) # True
print(check_zip_code("90210 is a TV show")) # False
print(check_zip_code("Their address is: 123 Main Street, Anytown, AZ 85258-0001.")) # True
print(check_zip_code("The Parliament of Canada is at 111 Wellington St, Ottawa, ON K1A0A9.")) # False
```

Comment: Considering that the zip code must be preceded by a space, the requirement "...and cannot be at the start of the text." is superfluous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

```
(?!\A)\b\d{5}(?:-\d{4})?\b
```

Full code:

```
import re

def check_zip_code (text):
    m = re.search(r'(?!\A)\b\d{5}(?:-\d{4})?\b', text)
    return True if m else False

print(check_zip_code("The zip codes for New York are 10001 thru 11104.")) # True
print(check_zip_code("90210 is a TV show")) # False
print(check_zip_code("Their address is: 123 Main Street, Anytown, AZ 85258-0001.")) # True
print(check_zip_code("The Parliament of Canada is at 111 Wellington St, Ottawa, ON K1A0A9.")) # False
```

---

Meanwhile I found that there's a package called [**`zipcodes`**](https://pypi.org/project/zipcodes/) which might be of additional help.

Comment: You could distinguish your answer by having your regex assert (with an alternation) that the five required digits constitutes a [valid zip code](https://www.phaster.com/zip_code.html). I've made a note to check back next week to see if you've done that.

Comment: Surely you didn't think my suggestion was serious!

Answer (score 1):

```
import re


def check_zip_code (text):
    return bool(re.search(r" (\b\d{5}(?!-)\b)| (\b\d{5}-\d{4}\b)", text))


assert check_zip_code("The zip codes for New York are 10001 thru 11104.") is True
assert check_zip_code("90210 is a TV show") is False
assert check_zip_code("Their address is: 123 Main Street, Anytown, AZ 85258-0001.") is True
assert check_zip_code("The Parliament of Canada is at 111 Wellington St, Ottawa, ON K1A0A9.") is False

assert check_zip_code("x\n90201") is False
assert check_zip_code("the zip somewhere is 98230-0000") is True
assert check_zip_code("the zip somewhere else is not 98230-00000000") is False
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
def check_zip_code (text):
  result = re.search(r"\d{5}[-\.d{4}]", text)
  return result != None

print(check_zip_code("The zip codes for New York are 10001 thru 11104.")) # True
print(check_zip_code("90210 is a TV show")) # False
print(check_zip_code("Their address is: 123 Main Street, Anytown, AZ 85258-0001.")) # True
print(check_zip_code("The Parliament of Canada is at 111 Wellington St, Ottawa, ON K1A0A9.")) # False
```

**Try this one**

Answer (score 1):

The first character must have a space.
This is an example of this problem only

```
r"[\s][\d]{5}"
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code you will get

```
import re
def check_zip_code (text):
  result = re.search(r"\s+\d{5}-?(\d{4})?", text)
  return result != None
```

Comment: This is matching ` 12345-` or ` 123456789` but not `12345`

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
def check_zip_code (text):
    result = re.search(r" \d{5}|\d[5]-\d{4}", text)
    return result != None
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this covers all the conditions
`result = re.search(r"\s\d{5}?(-\d{4})?", text)`

Comment: [Please do not post an answer that consists essentially of
code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer). Please [edit] your
answer to include an explanation of how and why the code solves the problem,
when it should be used, what its limitations are, and if possible a link to
relevant documentation.

Answer (score 0):

This code works perfect and generates required output.

```
import re

   def check_zip_code (text):

   result = re.search(r" \d{5}(-\d{4})?", text)

   return result != None

print(check_zip_code("The zip codes for New York are 10001 thru 11104.")) # True
print(check_zip_code("90210 is a TV show")) # False
print(check_zip_code("Their address is: 123 Main Street, Anytown, AZ 85258-0001.")) # True
print(check_zip_code("The Parliament of Canada is at 111 Wellington St, Ottawa, ON K1A0A9.")) # False
```

> ```
> True
> False
> True
> False
> ```